# p5.js How to change text thickness (smaller)?

Tags: javascript, tags, p5.js

TO BE CLEAR: I know how to change the size of text, I want to change the thickness of the text without changing the font. Is this possible?

The code below is basic code that makes the word "text" appear in the middle of your canvas. What would I have to change or add to make the text thickness thinner?

---

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  noStroke();
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(40);
  text("text", width / 2, height / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attempt to manipulate the points in p5.Font textToPoints:

- https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Font/textToPoints

Notice that e.g. multiplying every x by 0.8 would make the letters 80% thinner -- but it would also make whole character 80% thinner, and the entire word / sentence 80% shorter (compressing space between letters), so it would be more like horizontal scaling.

You could process one letter at a time.

You could also do fancy point math -- like erosion, or point gravity attraction. However it might be easier to just pick a different font and not manipulate the points at all....

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to make the text lines thinner. You could decrease the font size using the `textSize()` function, but that will make everything smaller, not just thinner.

Instead, your best bet is probably to use a different font, and set it using the `textFont()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textFont).